# What is the standard ftp service of ubuntu server 12.04?

Tags: ftp, ubuntu-12.04, sftp

Stopped vsftpd, so it is not that. If i can still access via ftp (sftp in particular) how do i now what service is managing it?

Comment: If I am not mistaking, vsftpd does not function as sftp server, so there was no need to shut it down. The confusion comes from the name vSFTPd. But that is not correct VS stands for very secure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If i can still access via ftp (sftp in particular)

Despite the name, **SFTP is not FTP**. It's an entirely separate SSH file transfer protocol, usually hosted by sshd (on the usual SSH port).

Not to be confused with FTPS, which *is* FTP (over SSL) and would be hosted by vsftpd.

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command:

```
netstat --listening --program
```

Note: You may get more information running it as root.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use following:

for sftp:

```
netstat -nap | grep -e ":22"
```

for ftp

```
netstat -nap | grep -e ":21"
```

These two commands will give you the programs that are listenning on ports 22 (ssh) and 21 (ftp)

My best guess is that in your case it is going to be `dropbear` or `openssh` listening on port 22

If you are looking for an sftp service, then vsftpd will most likely have nothing to do with it

Comment: Thank you very much. Technically this tells me what service is up to managing ftp/sftp. In my case was indeed openssh